# HP DV7-3166NR corrupt BIOS lights stopped blinking

Tags: bios

Black screen and at first caps lock blinking twice to indicate corrupt BIOS. Now no blinking lights. Have tried removing RAM, CMOS, hard reset, WIN+B, and HD and plugging all back in.

Comment: Any beep sound related to RAM failure or Corrupted BIOS firmware? Remove the RAM and check for any beep sound. Else, you would require to diagnosis your mother board with all other factors

Comment: Looks like you covered a lot of bases. But what exactly are you asking us?  Your motherboard BIOS reported it was corrupt, and now it's dead.  Replacing the motherboard seems like the next logical step, so have you contacted HP yet?

Comment: No beeping. I wouldn't say I am ignorant of PC parts/repairs, but not professionally educated in that field. I haven't tried to boot from USB stick w/ BIOS update/recovery yet. I will work on that step next and if it doesn't work, what exactly am I replacing/what is causing the failure? I could install a new motherboard, but are there other parts I am overlooking before replacement? What about the CPU hinge under the fan? Haven't explored that far disassembling, but is it a possibility the hinge came loose? Sorry to be all over the place, but I am very grateful y'all took the time to reply.